# "Error: spawn cmd ENOENT" In Expo Init Project

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm, expo, enoent

I am starting a new React-Native Project using

> expo init firstexpo

But I get this **error** at Command Prompt

**Error: spawn cmd ENOENT**

```
PS C:\Users\Alex\testing\firstexpo> expo start
[16:21:09] Starting project at C:\Users\Alex\testing\firstexpo
[16:21:11] Expo DevTools is running at http://localhost:19002
[16:21:11] Opening DevTools in the browser... (press shift-d to disable)
Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:232:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:407:16)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
PS C:\Users\Alex\testing\firstexpo>
```

**npm start error** Cannot find module 'opn'

```
[16:38:49] Starting project at C:\Users\Alex\testing\firstexpo
[16:38:52] Expo DevTools is running at http://localhost:19002
[16:38:52] Opening DevTools in the browser... (press shift-d to disable)
[16:38:52] Cannot find module 'opn'
[16:38:52] Set EXPO_DEBUG=true in your env to view the stack trace.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! empty-project-template@ start: `expo start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the empty-project-template@ start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-11-24T08_38_52_344Z-debug.log
```

**I am very new to coding, can anyone tell me how can I solve the problem?
Thank you very much.**

[Downgrade to v28](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5mq58.png)

Comment: do you have expo-cli installed in your project? can you delete your node_modules folder and run 'npm install'?

Comment: Yes, installed + expo-cli@2.4.0. Deleted node_modules folder and run npm install, same result.  Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:232:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:407:16)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)

Comment: ok, run 'npm install opn' and try again

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.
+ opn@5.4.0
added 2 packages from 1 contributor, updated 1 package and audited 22081 packages in 22.115s
found 0 vulnerabilities

But sadly, I still having the Error: spawn cmd ENOENT

Comment: Try setting the expo version to 28.0.0 at your package.json file, then run `npm install`. Many users have reported that `expo init` is broken for newer versions.

Comment: @romin21 I changed to "expo": "^28.0.0", but it still showing Error: spawn cmd ENOENT

Answer (score 8):

I solved my error using this. "%SystemRoot%\system32;" in the PATH variable.

Comment: How did you discover that?

Comment: @haleonj I found this solution from a GitHub discussion.

Answer (score 0):

**1- First you need to edit system environment variable and locate where you have Windows Poweshell so add new in "system environment variable path"**

[image: Add Window Powershell path in system environment variable path]

**2- Then Open Window PoweShell as An Administraror And Write these Two Commands :**

> :) Upgrade Window PowerShell because your nodejs and npm is updated but powershell is not updated so its making conflict with your npm start or expo start,so you should need to upgrade windows powershell

[image: Upgrade Window PowerShell because your nodejs and npm is updated but powershell is not updated so its making conflict with your npm start or expo start,so you should need to upgrade windows powershell.]

And Then run Cmd and also run your poject npm start or expo start so quickly it will work!

[image]

**BEST OF LUCK!**

Answer (score 0):

I got this error everytime I tried to open my app in Expo Go. I did clean all the Expo Go app data in my cell phone and my app run again.